# Escape "+" in JavaScript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the code I am trying to execute

```
input.replace(/^.+?(?=\+)/, ''), "i")
```

I have escape plus with `\+` but I get error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat
```

Kindly let me know how to escape `+` in the above regexp.

Comment: Are you sure that's your actual regex?  [regex101 seems to think it's fine](https://regex101.com/r/xZ3bZ1/1).

Comment: I'm not an expert on javascript, but I think you need to put your regex in quotes based on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: That can’t be real code, your round brackets don’t make sense. (And once that’s fixed, the code doesn’t throw any errors.)

Comment: @soong `/.../` is the syntax for an inline regular expression.

Comment: The regex `/^.+?(?=\+)/` does not produce the error described in the question.

Comment: works here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ejjyn9fm/1/

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? The partial line above -- partial because there's an extra `, "i")` at the end -- is fine once the extra parts are removed. Can you include the actual, intact code producing the error?

Comment: I vote to close, since this code does not produce the error described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put the i modifier at the end of the regex - not as a separate parameter. For example:

```
input.replace(/^.+?(?=\+)/i, '');
```

As @LorenzMeyer has pointed out, you don't actually need the i modifier, because the case is irrelevant based on your regex. Perhaps you need a global replace? In which case your replace would look like this:

```
input.replace(/^.+?(?=\+)/g, '');
```

Comment: The `i` is not necessary. I don't see anything case sensitive here.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer This is true.